# How to Set Two Instances of a Class Equal to Each Other by VALUE c#

Tags: c#

I want to be able to set one instance of a class equal another BY VALUE. I.E. I don't want to change a property in one instance and have the change appear in the other. And it *CAN'T BE A STRUCT*

Given theses classes:

```
class Main(string args[]) {
  Dictionary<string, FT> dic = new Dictionary<string, FT>();
  FT ft = new FT();
  ft.Name = "1";
  dic.Add("a", ft);
  ft.Name = "2";
  Console.WriteLine(dic["a"].Name);

  Console.ReadKey();
}

class FT {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you run this it will (should) printout '2'. That is not what I need. I need to still print '1'. And it CAN'T be a struct

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I can't just do:

```
var x = new FT();
x.Name = this.Name;
```

Because I will have easily 100 properties and variables in the end. And doing:

```
x.propertyName = this.propertyName;
```

100 times, is VERY inefficient.

Comment: So you need to create a new instance of `FT` with the same `Name` property value, e.g. `list.Add("a", new FT { Name = ft.Name });`. It becomes much more complicated when you have properties which are *also* of a mutable type...

Comment: (I'd also suggest that calling a `Dictionary<,>` variable `list` is a bit confusing, as it's not a list...)

Comment: I think the answer from Deepak or the comment above from Jon make both sense. If you explain us what you are trying to achieve and why you don't want to use a struct we might find a much elegant solution.

Comment: I basicly trying to keep a "clone" of 'ft' in the dictionary to be use as a template later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
ft= new FT ();
```

Before changing value to 2

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
list.Add( "a", ft.Clone() );
```

where `Clone()` is defined as

```
class FT {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FT Clone() {
        var x = new FT();
        x.Name = this.Name;
        return x;
    }
}
```